# Query With Conditional If Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to write a query that would select another row if the first one is not found ie grab a 'default' if it can't find the one specified.

Something similar to this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
teams
WHERE
team=:team_id
ELSE
WHERE team=1
```

Is this possible to do in Mysql?

BTW the default could be anything not just 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

supposing `:team_id` is greater than `1` you could do

```
select * from teams where team=1 or team=:team_id order by team desc limit 1
```

or if you don't know the order of both id :

```
select * from teams where team=1 or team=:team_id order by team=:team_id desc limit 1
```

Comment: +1 Clever.  For the sake of a (more) complete/flexible answer (and so I learn even more from this short/sweet answer), would you mind suggesting how you'd handle this if it was not known if the specified value was greater/less than the default?

Comment: @Sepster valid question even in this scenario (if the default is not team=1)

Comment: @Sepster see edit. But it probably doesn't apply as OP as the default id is 1.

Comment: Thanks. I've never seen that "sort by column=value" syntax.  Going to take a peek at the mysql docco now to see what else I've missed there (I've a MSSQL background, where this is not available).  Glad I asked the question :-)

Comment: I should have said that the default could be anything not just 1. I will try your solutions and get back to you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE team=:team_id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE team=1
ORDER BY team=1
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at my question again I've thought maybe its easier to do then I originally thought.

Would the following not work?:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
teams
WHERE
team=:team OR (team!=:team AND team=:default_team)
```

Comment: This won't do what you specified in the question.